# What metrics should I use to describe the difference between two magnitude responses in octave band

Tags: frequency-spectrum, dft, frequency-response

Suppose that I have two frequency responses $H_1(k)$ and $H_2(k)$, I want to describe the difference or MSE between them in each octave band. The background is that I have a target frequency response $H_1(k)$ and I design a filter whose frequency response is $H_2(k)$ in order to approximate the target. Now I want to measure how good my filter is. Should I take dB first and then calculate the average value or in the contrary?

The first way should be like this:

$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\Big|20\log|H_1(k)| - 20\log |H_2(k)|\Big|
$$

The second way is
$$
20\log\Bigg( \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\Big||H_1(k)| - |H_2(k)|\Big|\Bigg)
$$

where $N$ is the total number of frequency bins in each octave band.

I think the first one is correct but I'm not sure. Or otherwise should I use something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any metric will depend on what matters for your specific application. If you want something that looks good on paper, chose a metric that represents what "looks good" means. if you have a communication application, you look at bit error rates. If you want something that sounds good, you should use a metric that's perceptually motivated.

The latter is rather complicated since human auditory perception is rather complicated as well. As a first order approximation it's logarithmic in both frequency and loudness, so a good start would be to apply pink weighting sum the energy over the band and then apply dB() to it.

Octave bands are also rather larger, so 1/3 octaves would probably give more accurate results.

Comment: Thank you Hilmar. Many papers show their results in an ambiguous way such as "dB - MSE" or "magnitude error (dB)" but they don't give any formula about the metrics. I don't think that's a proper way, that confuses me a lot.

Comment: I agree with what you said in the first paragraph. But back to my question, by applying pink weighting sum of the energy and then apply dB, are you suggesting that I should take sum (or average since the higher frequency bands of octave have more frequency bins) first and then dB?

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything, since I don't know what your specific application is and what the requirements are. I just gave a few examples of potential metrics, but there are many more of those. Pick the one that's right for your specific problem

Comment: Thank you! I got it!